# How to get the last digit from every list value?

Tags: python, list

Hi I want to take the last number of values from a list.

Example:

```
my_list = [1234, 2345, 3456, 4567]
```

And I want a result like this.

```
my_list_result = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: @DanielHao Nah, yours is better, because it's at least correct. (Although you both violated the instruction "Avoid answering questions in comments").

Answer (score 3):

The last digit of any integer can be obtained using mod 10. So you can do this:

```
my_list_result = [x % 10 for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension like this

`my_list = [i%10 for i in my_list]`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the each item as a string and get the last element.  You can convert it back to int after as

[str(num)[-1] for num in my_list]

with convert back to int

[int(str(num)[-1]) for num in my_list]

Comment: You can, yes.  However inefficient given all the unnecessary conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
[int(str(n)[-1]) for n in my_list]
```

For each number in the list, turn it into a string, get the last character, and then turn that character into an int again.

Comment: it is significantly faster to use ```n%10```